# How can I display elements on the same line?

Tags: html, css

css positioning problem

```css
* {
  color: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}

header,
nav,
section,
article,
footer,
aside {
  padding: 2rem;
}

header {
  background-color: #FFC300;
}

nav {
  background-color: #FF5733;
}

section {
  background-color: #C70039;
}

article {
  background-color: #900C3F;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 10px auto;
}

aside {
  background-color: #cd6155;
}

footer {
  background-color: #581845;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    cabecera
  </header>
  <nav>
    navegación
  </nav>
  <section>
    sección
    <article>artículo</article>
    <article>artículo</article>
  </section>
  <aside> más información</aside>
  <footer>
    Pie de página
  </footer>
</main>
```

I want it to be the following way and I can't, if someone helps me I would appreciate it very much

[image: I want it to be the following way and I can't, if someone helps me I would appreciate it very much]

Comment: You could give your aside the following:

```css
aside {
    background-color: #cd6155;
    float: left;
    width: calc(50% - 4rem)
}
```

or use a wrapper element around footer and aside and make it flex.

```css
.mywrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

.mywrapper > * {
  flex: 1;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Instead of `<section>` and things like that try making a table with `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<th>`, and `<td>`.

I used [W3Schools tutorial on HTML Tables](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp). It should help you understand those tags.

Comment: Tables should only be used for displaying data. They're not for layout.